# Font letters ebgaramond with the Editor Texifier

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond, minutes

How to use **ebgaramond** `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` to have bold letters in **Editor Texifier**.
Although the font has bold letters in the package, there aren't in the output. At least the titles I would like to have in bold letters with the font garamond
I downloaded already the Extra fonts (A large collection of font packages,...)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{minutes}


\begin{document}
\begin{Protokoll}{Titel}
\untertitel{Untertitel}


\moderation{Name Moderator}
\maketitle
\topic{Begrüssung}
\textbf{This should be bold}, but isn't. Neither the title.
\end{Protokoll}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if I remove inputenc [I get bold using texlive 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4RgO.png) posts here are always utf-8 so the apple declaration generates errors

Comment: Why the `applemac` option?